# I Expected this code to throw an error as ival(local variable) is used outside the scope of try except, but why is it running without any error

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-except

I expected the following code to throw an error as the variable `ival`(local variable) is being used outside of its scope i.e., in if condition. I didn't encounter any issues/errors why? Please explain the reason.

```
rawstr=input('Enter a number')
try:
    ival=int(rawstr)
except:
    ival=-1
if ival>0:
    print('Nice work')
else:
    print('Not a Number')
```

I expected a traceback error saying `ival` is not defined.

Comment: `try` does not introduce scope. `ival` is just a global like `rawstr`.

Comment: The variable `ival` is local for the function, not only for the `try` part. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules